# How to enforce a encoding format when writing XML into Oracle Table in Mule 4?

Tags: oracle, dataweave, mule4, xmltype

When i was writing an XML into Oracle Table (column type as XMLTYPE ) its writing without showing any encoding type . This is a current process achieving through Java . We are migrating this process to Mule . In Mule the xml is writing into same table but after writing i see encoding format in that XML . Not sure how its coming , its not there actual xml .

XML in Table when inserting using Java

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

When Using Mule

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
```

The Code using in Mule to insert XML is below

```
'REQUEST_XML' : write(payload, 'application/xml'),
```

This is my insert statement

```
insert into xmlpkg.REQ_RESP (ID, REQUEST_XML) values (xmlpkg.SEQ_DV.nextval,   
:REQUEST_XML  )
```

I giving below in my Input Parameters

```
{
'REQUEST_XML'  : write(payload, 'application/xml')
}
```

My Payload is an xml but it will come as text , i cannot change it.

```
<DRIVERequest Version="1.00">
<Authentication PortalID="*****" Password="*******" Username="*******"/>
</DRIVERequest>
```

[image]

This is what i am seeing in log just before the insert operation

```
Before DB operation : "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n<DRIVERequest 
Version=\"1.00\">\n  <Authentication PortalID=\"*****\" Password=\"*******\" 
Username=\"*******\"/>\n</DRIVERequest>"
```

My transformation is

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
requestXML : write(payload, 'application/xml')
}
```

In Input Arguments i am taking it as below

```
{
'REQUEST_XML': payload.requestXML
}
```

In the log i am seeing as UTF-8 but after insert operation its showing as encoding="US-ASCII"

Comment: What is the payload? Please share the actual database connector operation and complete DataWeave transformation.

Comment: Updated the question with more info

Comment: Please do the transformation before the database operation and assign it to a variable so you can log it and share the result here.

Comment: Updated the info. Again its inserting the xml but why the encoding going away ?

Comment: How are you checking that ```"after insert operation its showing as encoding="US-ASCII" ```?

Comment: You can try to use the ```encoding``` writer property. Just change ```write(payload, 'application/xml')``` to ```write(payload, 'application/xml', {encoding: 'UTF-8 '})``` Ref: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-formats-xml#writer-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to be that it is not Mule but the Oracle JDBC driver is picking up the wrong encoding somewhere.

Possible solutions:

1. Ensure that you are using a recent JDBC driver.
2. Search for any environment variable in your operating system that could be setting the wrong encoding. For example NLS_LANG (see https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/974099/encoding-changed-after-updatexml)
3. Alternatively, try to set NLS_LANG explicitly to avoid any incorrect defaults.
4. Finally read Oracle documentation for other similar configurations that might affect the driver.

Comment: No , Tried to update the latest version of JDBC driver . Set explicitly NLS_LANG . But nothing works .

Comment: Still researching

Comment: made it working as per this link.  
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66557450/oracle-insert-xml-parameter-is-not-validating-in-mule