# Oracle insert XML parameter is not validating in Mule

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have an insert statement into Oracle **XMLTYPE** Column. When i am running it in Oracle its working fine . But if i place the same in Mule insert its not validating .

My XML is

```
'<DRIVEResponse><Loan><Condition ActionStep="parties. &amp;lt;A href=''ABC.com/abc/''"/> 
 </Loan>
 </DRIVEResponse>'
```

This what i placed in DB insert

```
 {
'RESPONSE_XML' : '<DRIVEResponse><Loan><Condition ActionStep="parties. 
 &amp;lt;A href=''ABC.com/abc/''"/> </Loan></DRIVEResponse>' ,
 'SUCCESS_FLAG' : "Y"
 }
```

Error i am receiving is

```
- Invalid input ''', expected `}` or ',' for the object expression.
```

(line 2, column 88):

The query text is coming from a java class . This same Query text is sending to one spring boot service and the insert is happening there. But in mule i am getting error as shown. If i run this query in SQL developer its running and inserting record.

[image]

Update :- insert Statement with hardcoded XML , is working fine .
But if i place that in a transformation and bring that variable into query , its failing . Even though i am making exact match with hardcoded value , if i place it in variable its failing .

Hardcoded  - Working fine

```
insert into xmlpkg.BLT_DV_REQ_RESP(ID, REQUEST_XML) values (
      xmlpkg.SEQ_DV_REQ_RESP.nextval, 
'<Condition  Code= "parties. &amp;lt;A 
 href=''h''&amp;gt;h/&amp;lt;/A&amp;gt;"></Condition>' )
```

Taking from Variable - Failing
Below code is in my transformation

```
 %dw 2.0
 output text/plain
 ---
 "'"++( '<Condition  Code= "parties. &amp;lt;A 
 href=\'\'h\'\'&amp;gt;h/preventfraud/&amp;lt;/A&amp;gt;"></Condition>' )  as 
 String ++ "'"
```

Comment: Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide  all details needed to understand the issue and how to reproduce. For example there are no details at all of the database, or of the Mule application. What does it mean when running on Oracle? What is the JSON shown? Is it relevant to the problem?
Also it should be in text. Please use text instead of images for text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: " i am getting error as shown" - where is the error message?

Comment: added the error i am seeing in Studio

Comment: Please add the database operation in Mule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string for RESPONSE_XML is incorrectly escaped. You are trying to put an XML document as a string expression in DataWeave. However the quotes are unbalanced and/or incorrectly escaped after `href=`. I'm not sure what is the original XML document is. If this is by hand, it would be better to let DataWeave to escape it automatically, and correctly, for example using something like `write(xmlPayload, "application/xml") as String`.

Example:

```
        <ee:transform doc:name="Mock result from a request" doc:id="723fdd83-fcce-4bff-8a24-065609b235b0" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
{
    book: {
            name: "Robin Hood"
    }   
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Do some transform" doc:id="aaca98c2-1f76-476f-8ab3-030061e46472" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload.book mapObject (title: $) ]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Prepare arguments for db operation" doc:id="261e8437-d7b5-4a8e-b781-5790ea5f9f40" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
    'RESPONSE_XML' : write(payload, "application/xml") ,
    'SUCCESS_FLAG' : "Y"
}
]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="a90fca6e-5fd3-4aaa-963c-0f06376e4076" message="output #[payload]"/>
```

Comment: @aled--> Although the XML looks to have unbalanced quotes, the XML is still valid(if you check here-->https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xml-validator). Lets say this XML was returned from a external service and this response we intend to pass it to  a stored procedure in DB after some transformations.How do we do that? Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: I'm adding an example mocking the values just to show the method. You can use variables instead of the payload.

Comment: The XML might be well formed by itself. The problem is that it uses the same characters that DataWeave uses to delimit strings. It is the combination of both in the same expression that causes the error.

Comment: I think what said you make sense here . I updated my question with hardcoded XML . Its inserting successfully when i hardcode the XML . If i make that string in transformation and refer that variable in insert statement , its failing .

Comment: Trying to double escape between two languages is hard and makes the result hard to read, but it is not imposible. Example: `read("<DRIVEResponse><Loan><Condition ActionStep=\"parties. 
 &amp;lt;A href=''ABC.com/abc/''\"/> </Loan></DRIVEResponse>", "application/xml")`. I don't think it is worth the effort and it is best to let DataWeave do, by generating it or by reading from a file instead of hardcoding. I used read() to confirm DataWeave can parse it.